# About completeness of complex exponential systems

Tags: complex-analysis, lp-spaces

If $\{\lambda_n\}_n$ is a certain sequence of real constants such that $\{e^{i\lambda_n x}\}$ is complete in $L^2\left(-\gamma,\gamma\right)$, could I say that $\{e^{i\lambda_n x}\}$ is complete in $L^2\left(0,2\gamma\right)$?

I think that in general the answer is negative so I would like to know if there is any sufficient condition providing it.

I have also a doubt about the following theorem (from "Gap and Density theorems" by Levinson, page 3):

"The sequence $\{e^{i\lambda_n x}\}, \quad \lambda_n>0$, is closed over an interval of length L if $\liminf_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{n}{\lambda_n}>\frac{L}{2\pi}$."

The interval of length $L$ has to be symmetric with respect to $0$ or not?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what is meant with $\{\exp [i\lambda _{n}x]\}$ being complete.
A basis? Anyway let us assume that the linear span of $\{\exp [i\lambda
_{n}x]\}$ is dense in $L^{2}(-\gamma ,+\gamma )$. Then
\begin{equation*}
\int_{-\gamma }^{+\gamma }dx\exp [i\lambda _{n}x]f(x)=0,\;\forall
n\;\Rightarrow \;f(x)=0
\end{equation*}
Now consider
\begin{equation*}
\int_{0}^{2\gamma }dy\exp [i\lambda _{n}y]f(y)=\exp [i\lambda _{n}\gamma
]\int_{-\gamma }^{+\gamma }dx\exp [i\lambda _{n}x]f(x+\gamma )=0,\;\forall n
\end{equation*}
Then  $f(x+\gamma )$ must vanish. Thus $\{\exp [i\lambda _{n}x]\}$ in $%
L^{2}(0,2\gamma )$ is complete in your sense.

As to your second question what do you mean by closed?